# Return GeoPoint(s) relative to user using line-of-site outside of MapView

Tags: android

I am currently writing a script to find the closest `GeoPoint` (from a list of `GeoPoints` located on our servers) relative to the user, however I came across and interesting idea on limiting results even further.

I am wondering if it is possible to take the Users current line-of-site, maybe using the `Compass` in order to ignore `GeoPoint`(s) that may or may not be closer to the user located behind them. I am not looking for this code to be written for me, just a nudge in the right direction or any suggestions, I have searched for the past couple days and am coming up empty.
*When I say "line-of-site" I don't mean to specify a cone as shown below, limiting to a direction of N, S, E or W would be fine.*

In the exmaple picture below I want the results to show only GeoPoint(2):

[image]

**Explanation of use:** The user goes to a location to take photos of *several things* at said location. In my Camera Activity I am writing a script to show a historic photo of one of the elements on-site relative to their location. All site-specific historic photos and their Coordinates have been retrieved and parsed using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.  It gives a number of examples including how to calculate bearing and distance to a point (longitude, latitude).

Check the bearing and distance fall within your `acceptable` range, whatever that may be (direction, line of sight...).

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at that exact page (got it from [GPS Visualizers page source](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators#bearing)), found the formula for determining bearing, I think this will work for me. To my understanding I could find the bearings for all `GeoPoints`, then compare that to the second parameter in `onSensorChanged`, let me know if I am headed in the wrong direction, pun intended :)

Comment: It depends on which `Sensor` you are using.  Generally a bearing will be calculated from the `Accelerometer` and `Magnetometer` sensors (`Orientation` is deprecated) or the GPS.